# properly dealing with null database values in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable, isnull

I am looping thorugh a datatable and and printing each row to the console and I keep on getting a dbnull error.  I inserted an if statement in my loop to try and catch it, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
                Do While reader.Read
                For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1

                    If reader.IsDBNull(i) Then
                        Console.Write(Nothing)
                    Else
                        Console.Write(reader.GetString(i))
                    End If

                Next
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine())
```

Comment: Check if you are really getting a DBNull error and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing Console.Write(Nothing) to Console.Write("Nothing") might remove one error, and reader.GetString(i) might throw InvalidCastException errors - you should catch this. reader.IsDBNull(i), however, looks correct.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't like the write(nothing).  I ended up just putting " , " as the string and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the reader methods, but Console.Write(Nothing) would likely have issues.  Try this:

```
        Do While reader.Read
        For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1

            If reader.Item(i) Is DBNull.Value Then
                Console.Write("")
            Else
                Console.Write(CStr(reader.Item(i)))
            End If

        Next
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine())
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply change it to

```
        If NOT isdbnull(reader.Item(i)) Then
            Console.Write("")
        Else
            Console.Write(CStr(reader.Item(i)))
        End If
```

That has always worked better for me. I dont know if there is a DBNull vs DBNull.value issue here.